# UITableView with two Columns but not two different TableViews

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, xcode4.2

I am working on a requirement where I need to have a TableView with two columns which should not be independent of each other. So I am not looking for two TableViews which scroll independently instead single TableView with two columns which can scroll together. In each of the column I again need to fill up data and a screenshot.

So as far now I have modified the code in the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    static NSString *secondCellIdentifier = @"Cell2";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:secondCellIdentifier];

    if (cell2 == nil) {
        cell2 = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:secondCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

    cell2.textLabel.text = [tableList2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *twoColumnRowView = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];

    [twoColumnRowView addSubview:cell];
    [twoColumnRowView addSubview:cell2];

    return twoColumnRowView;
}
```

But unfortunately I am not getting a two columned table, instead I am getting a weird output which can been seen in the screenshot.

[image]

Can someone guide me in the right direction.

P.S. I have gone through previous posts in the same forum and on internet regarding the same topic but nothing with proper explanation or example. Would be good to get a helpful information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a custom UITableViewCell that has the layout you are looking for. Then you can instantiate it in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

Comment: but I have done the same in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. Correct me if I am wrong. On the other hand if you have any example, then that would be good

Answer (score 0):

Make Your custom UITableViewCell Class. Inside the cell  put two UIButton and set them according to your layOut.